# The correct way to load third party scripts?

Tags: javascript

With a bit of help from Stackoverflow I've managed to display blog content from Tumblr on my own website.

**I've noticed that if the Tumblr site is slow, it effects the page loading speed of my own website.**

I found [this article](http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write) on javascript.info. The article recommends using this code to create a variable of the external script URL.

```
 var script = document.createElement('script')
 script.src = 'http://ads.com/buyme?rand='+Math.random()

 // now append the script into HEAD, it will fetched and executed
 document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script)
```

I (kind of) understand what's happening in the first two lines, but I don't understand how to use the last bit of the code:

```
 document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script)
```

**How would I add the `script` variable into the `src` of the script?**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="URL OF SCRIPT TO GO HERE"></script>
```

Hope someone can help, this'd be useful for other third party scripts on my site.

## UPDATE

Thanks to 'The Spooniest' for helping with this (see thread below).

I was having problems getting this to work with my current page, so I decided to strip it down and create a basic page to see if I could get just this script working.

The code below works, it drops the Javascript just before the `</head>` tag. Great! However there's somehting that bothers me when I inspect the page (using Dev Tools) I see this warning:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ?rand=0.9741437959019095:1
```

Any ideas why this appears? Is it a problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
var script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = 'http://ads.com?rand=' + Math.random()

// now append the script into HEAD, it will fetched and executed
document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script)
</script>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>A basic page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

### UDATE 2

**Figured out what the problem was. The URL in the script wasn't a .js file. When I enter a URL linking to a .js file (which I want) it works a treat!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You already added it.**

Let's look over the code again:

```
var script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = 'http://ads.com/buyme?rand='+Math.random()

// now append the script into HEAD, it will fetched and executed
document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script)
```

The first line creates the element that will become your `script` tag. The second line sets `script.src` to a particular URL: in this case it's to an ad site, but you would want to use the URL of your Tumblr code instead. The third line puts the your script at the end of the first tag inside the document element (which in this case means the `head`).

The magic happens in the first two lines. `document.createElement` looks at the name of the tag you're creating, in order to figure out the proper class to use for the element: for `'script'`, that means using HTMLScriptElement. **This particular class knows that when you set its `src` property, that's supposed to go in the `src` attribute of the `script` tag.** The instance you created remembers this even after you put it into the document, and so that's how the attribute gets there.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining it so clearly. I've added the code above in between the <head></head> tags after jQuery, but I get an error. Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method. Any ideas why it spits out this error?

Comment: That's a strange error for something like this, but try `document.body.appendChild` instead. All DOM nodes should in theory support appendChild, but maybe there's something in the text of your page that is creating some strange node before the `head`. `document.body` goes straight for the document's `body` tag, that that definitely supports appendChild.

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time to look at this. It works, but it displays a warning. I've updated the question to show the code.

Comment: `document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script)` works on the basic demo I created, so it must be something related to the page I was working on - something else to tinker with! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script)
```

The above code will add the script to the head tag of your page. As  `document.documentElement.firstChild` will point to head tag.

You don't have to add `script` variable into src, since it's already taken care by javascript code.

It's generally suggested that javasript files should always be added at the bottom of the page. So that the page loads faster.

Comment: Thanks for replying to this. I was wondering, does the javascript add the script at the start of the <head> tag or at the end?